# How to convert from an HTTP response to an object that I can use in Typescript?

Tags: angular

As you can see, I am a new user. I have an HTTP response when I submit a form through ngSubmit. I want to use that response and use it as an object so that I can re-use this object in my Typescript file.

Map.html

```
<form [formGroup]="originCityForm" (ngSubmit)="getOriginCity(originCityForm)">
   <input
     matInput
     type="text"
     placeholder="Origin city"
     formControlName="origin"
   />
 </form>
```

Map.ts

```
originCity : City;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.originCityForm = this.fb.group({
      origin: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]]
    });
    this.originCity = new City();
  }

  getOriginCity(originCityForm: FormGroup) {
    const o = new City();
    this.service.getCity(originCityForm.value.origin).subscribe(
      city => {
        o.id = city.id;
        o.title = city.title;
        o.latitude = city.latitude;
        o.longitude = city.longitude;
        o.destination = city.destination;
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
    console.log(o); // It will print the request response as an object (Which is what I want)
    originCityForm.reset();
  } 

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      console.log(this.originCity) // When I print, this.originCity is null
    }
```

I receive the response that I expected. However I don't know how to take this response and make it an object City so that I can use it in another method in the Typescript file.

Answer (score 0):

*I may have misunderstood the question prior to edits, hopefully my answer is helpful. Apoligies if not.*

---

Unfortunately, there is no way to automatically do what you are wanting.

You will need to manually map the plain old JavaScript object returned from your service to an instance of the City class.

It may be better to do this mapping within your `getCity` method:

```
return this.httpClient.get(CITY_URL)
  .pipe(
    map(plainOldJavascriptObject => new City(...))
  );
```

Alternatively, if the `City` class has no behavior (ie functions) it may be better to use an Interface, in which case no mapping is needed.

Comment: I would like to use interface as you suggested to me, but I don't know how. Here is the code: 
``` 
export interface City {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  destination: City;
}


 getCity(title: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<City>(this.baseUrl + '/api/' + title)
      .pipe(response => new City());
  }

```

Comment: You can't use the `new` operator with TypeScript interfaces, only classes. In your example above there is no need to call `new City()`. In fact, you should be able to remove the entire `.pipe(response => new City())`. (that syntax doesn't look quite right).

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you need to just type response?

```
  originCity: City;

  getOriginCity(originCityForm: FormGroup) {
    this.service.getCity(originCityForm.value.origin).subscribe(
      (city:City) => {
        console.log(city);
        this.originCity = city;
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
    originCityForm.reset();
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I did that but I cannot use originCity in ngAfterViewInit() as getOriginCity(originCityForm:FormGroup) is a function in the map.html : 
`(ngSubmit)="getOriginCity(originCityForm)`
. How can I use it in ngAfterViewInit()? Thanks @Sergey Rudenko :)